# About Displaying a DICOM image in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to Display a DICOM image in C#. Thanks to Steve, I've been able to read in the DICOM file. However, want to display the DICOM image, I have a code which seem to attempt to display the image, however it has a single error.  The code is posted below. The error being displayed is as follows.

Error   1

> The name 'image1' does not exist in the current context   C:\Users\Don
>   jar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\DICOMCA\DICOMCA\Form1.cs    52  13  DICOMCA

```
 string filename = @"C:\Users\Don jar\Pictures\Xray pics\fluro.dcm";
 DicomFile dicomFile = new DicomFile(filename);
 dicomFile.Load(DicomReadOptions.Default);
 foreach (DicomAttribute attribute in dicomFile.DataSet)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0}, Value: {1}", attribute.Tag.Name, attribute.ToString());
 }

 int bitsPerPixel = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.BitsStored).GetInt32(0, 0);
 int width = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.Columns).GetInt32(0, 0);
 int height = dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.Rows).GetInt32(0, 0); 
 int stride = width * 2;
 byte[] bitmapBuffer = (byte[])dicomFile.DataSet.GetAttribute(DicomTags.PixelData).Values;


 BitmapSource bitmapSource = BitmapImage.Create(width, height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Gray16, null, bitmapBuffer, stride);

 image1.Source = bitmapSource;
```

Comment: This is more a C# programming problem than dicom, I removed the [dicom] tag

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `image1` is not defined anywhere in your source so the compiler can't make any sense of `image1.Source = bitmapSource;`.